# How to delete commit from locat git repository at phpstorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm and have a problem.

I've committed few files in PHPStorm (cmd+k). But it was a mistake and i shouldn't push'em. Now i don't understand, how to reset/delete that commit from phpstorm.

I used git reset --hard at Terminal, but nothing changed in PHPStorm - commit's still there. I can see it, if i'm trying to push (shift+cmd+k), then I see all previous commits.

Answer (score 11):

As long as the commit has not made it upstream yet, a command-line solution would be:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

The `HEAD^` refers to the last commit *before* `HEAD`. `HEAD` represents the latest commit. When you use `git reset` without another argument, it resets to the latest commit. But that's exactly the point you're already at.

Adding `--hard` cleans up the added/edited files from your working directory. Decide for yourself if that's something you want.

Comment: git reset HEAD^

Still, see same committed files in phpstorm window :(

Comment: That's why I tried to explain `--hard`. If you want to remove the files as well as undo the commit, try `git reset HEAD^ --hard`, but note that you will lose the edits made in the last commit.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Git button on the left-bottom of the IDE, if I click it I can see both my local and remote branches. If you click on a branch you can see all the commits in a timeline and you can delete them by just right-clicking on them and select Undo commit. Notice that you have to delete them in the order you added them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `git revert <commit_sha>` to revert the commit you don't want. It doesn't delete a commit but does an undo of what was done in the commit.

Answer (score 1):

VCS > Git > Rebase

The Git integration with PhpStorm supports the Rebase operation and provides interface that ensures high flexibility in setting rebase arguments.
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/rebasing-branches.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar. In my case I committed and pushed up to github. But 2 of the files were too large and wouldn't transfer. I really don't need them anyway, so I deleted them from my hard drive
. I then tried to push again, since the first push failed. But I get the same size error from the push. Should I reset the entire commit, commit again, and then try to push again?